# Docker with Ruby REPL on current folder

Tags: ruby, docker

I'm working on a small ruby directory with a few files, I want to run ruby REPL(inside a docker image) with access to all files in my current folder(eg. ).

I don't want to build a new container everything time that I change some file, is that possible? I've looked a docker documentation, but I can't figure out.

Comment: you can SSH into the docker container and edit the files there

Comment: Look at docker volumes, as noted. Or Look at docker compose. You can see an example of setting up volumes to mount the current directory into your docker container here: https://github.com/rubyforgood/ghgvc/blob/master/docker-compose.yml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is [Docker Volumes](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/).

Here is a proof of concept:

Step 1. Create an IRB REPL (or other if you wish) that requires your library:

```
# console.rb
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require "irb"
require "irb/completion" # easy tab completion
require_relative "test"

Dir.chdir '/app'
IRB.start
```

Step 2. Use this as the `test` file, as required by the console script above:

```
# test.rb
def hello
  puts "world"
end
```

Step 3. Run IRB from the container, while mounting the current directory into the container. I am using my own alpine Ruby image here, but you can choose whatever Ruby image you want (assuming it comes with IRB) or build your own image.

```
$ docker run --rm -it --volume $PWD:/app dannyben/alpine-ruby ruby /app/console.rb
```

Step 4: At this point, you should be inside the IRB console, and be able to run your code:

```
irb(main):002:0> hello
world
```

Step 5: When changing your code, you will need to load it again with:

```
irb(main):003:0> load 'test.rb'
=> true
```

(Or, exit the container and run it again - no rebuild needed).